# What is the function electrical device?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, relay

What is the function of the device in the picture. Unfortunately, I did not make a full diagram of how it was wired, but the hot and the corresponding neutral were connected  by crimp-on leads on the right side. The hot was downstream from a lutron dimmer and there were three other 14/2 wires in the box which I'm not sure where they led to.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the front of the device?

Comment: This is the front of the device. The plastic box is mounted on a 2x6.

Comment: Can you show at an angle?  It kinda looks like a contractor or relay.  Is there any writing anywhere?

Comment: Can you take it out of the box and get a picture from the side?

Answer (score 2):

That is a contactor.  With the proper electrical signal to a coil underneath it magnetically draws the switching plate across the contact points and closed the circuit.  This type of unit is typically rated for 15 to 40-Amps.  It is an electrically operated switch for heavier loads.

Comment: Likely used in this case to switch more than one circuit simultaneously... but being downstream from a lutron dimmer makes no sense.